# AJAX Requstet JSON Output returned first right and then [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, momentjs

I received the output for my mustache template first completely right, but when I try to encode it with `JSON.parse()`, it will output `[object Object]`. I don't know why?

**First Output:**

> {Inhalt: Array(27)}
>   Inhalt
>   :
>   Array(27)
>   0
>   :
>   begin
>   :
>   "08.03.2018"
>   can_remove
>   :
>   true
>   creator
>   :
>   "test"
>   creator_date
>   :
>   "06.03.2018 08:18"
>   end
>   :
>   "22.03.2018"
>   est
>   :
>   "Standard"
>   id
>   :
>   27
>   notes
>   :
>   "utc test"
>   status_accepted
>   :
>   false
>   status_none
>   :
>   true
>   status_progress
>   :
>   false
>   status_rejected
>   :
>   false
>   status_removed
>   :
>   false
>   time_from
>   :
>   "08:00"
>   time_until
>   :
>   "11.00"
>   work
>   :
>   "Kranken- und Altenpflegehelfer/in"
>   worker
>   :
>   58
>   **proto** (here are before and after __ )
>   :
>   Object

**My code:**

```
  function getFrame() {
$.when(
  $.ajax("mustache/templates/Liste/iFrame.mustache"),
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "lister.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    cache: false
  }))
  .done(function(tpl, data) {
    var template = tpl[0];
    var renderdata = data[0];
    console.log(renderdata);
    var rendered = Mustache.render(template,renderdata);
    $('#frame').html(rendered);

  let encoder = JSON.parse(data[0]);
  console.log(encoder);
 let startDate = encoder.Inhalt.begin;
  let startTime = encoder.Inhalt.time_from;
  let endDate = encoder.Inhalt.end;
  let endTime = encoder.Inhalt.time_until;
  let id = encoder.Inhalt.id;

  var mergedBegin = startDate + " " + ClientOffset + " " + startTime;
  var mergedEnd = endDate + " " + ClientOffset + " " + endTime;
  var stillUtcBegin = moment.utc(mergedBegin).toDate();
  var stillUtcEnd = moment.utc(mergedEnd).toDate();
  var localBegin = moment(stillUtcBegin).local().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');
  var localEnd = moment(stillUtcEnd).local().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm');

  console.log(id + ":begin: " + localBegin);
  console.log(id + ":end: " + localend);
});
  };




function ConvertUtcOffset(offset) {
    let prefix = Math.floor(offset/60);
    let postfix = offset%(60);
    if (prefix >= 0 && prefix < 10) {
      prefix = "0"+prefix;
    } else
    if (prefix < 0 && prefix > -10) {
      prefix = "-0"+Math.Abs(prefix);
    }
    if (postfix >= 0 && postfix < 10) {
      postfix = "0"+postfix;
    }
    return prefix + ":" + postfix;
  };
```

I try to edit the incoming times (UTC) to the users local time.

I hope you could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are trying to do is stringify it?

```
// data: Serialized Array of objects (Names & Values).
console.log(data);

console.log('3. Stringify this Serialized Array of objects (Names & Values)');

// Stringify Serialized Array of objects.
data = JSON.stringify(data);
```